# SWF won't play on local browser

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I have a swf file that use url to a local wamp server where it reads the respond XML (PHP). When I try to play the swf from my local machine using Flash Player, the player - in first try - refused to play saying that the swf need authority to run and to do so I should click "Setting" that comes with the message. I gave the folder the authority its needed and it's working fine now.

But, when I tried to run it using the web browser, it stops after requesting the url. Any idea what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: When exporting SWF make sure you have "allow Network access" enabled in your output options (are you using a Flash IDE like **CS** or **Animate**?).

Comment: If your script is on another domain than your swf you will need a crossdomain file on that script server

Comment: I am using Flash CS6. I did that but no luck!